# Vertical spacing with underbrace command

Tags: math-mode, spacing, braces

How can I set how much vertical spacing is put between my equation and the curly bracket used in underbrace?

As an example, I feel like the following just puts the brace too close to the equation:

```
\underbrace{c = a + b}_{\text{my equation}}
```

Many thanks...

Answer (score 23):

You can put a `\strut` just before `c` to enlarge the depth of your equation and if you still find the curly bracket too close, you can also define your own "strut":

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*\mystrut[1]{\vrule width0pt height0pt depth#1\relax}
\begin{document}
$\underbrace{c = a + b}_{\text{my equation}}$
$\underbrace{\strut c = a + b}_{\text{my equation}}$
$\underbrace{\mystrut{1.5ex}c = a + b}_{\text{my equation}}$
$\underbrace{\mystrut{2.5ex}c = a + b}_{\text{my equation}}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

The `mathtools` package has a very useful implementation of `\underbracket` and `\overbracket` that take two extra parameters: the gauge of the bracket and its distance from the text. From Sec. 3.3.2 (v. 1.10) of the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mh/mathtools.pdf):

```
\underbracket[〈rule thickness〉] [〈bracket height〉]{〈arg〉} 
\overbracket[〈rule thickness〉] [〈bracket height〉]{〈arg〉}
```

The `〈arg〉` can be of the form `{bracketed matter}_{label}` (or substituting `^` for `_` in the case of `\overbracket`).

The documentation discusses infelicities of spacing in the traditional `\underbrace` and `\overbrace`, and seems to be saying that the package contains a revised from of these, as well. If so the revised versions do not seem to be as finely adjustable as `\underbracket` and `\overbracket`, and they are not documented in the documentation.