# Diagonal brace with nested parenthesis

Tags: brackets, underbrace

I would to obtain a result similar to the image below.
So far I only have `\bigg( \Big(   \big( a^q \big)^q \Big)^{\rotatebox{25}{$\cdots$}} \bigg)^q`, without the brace.

I tried to follow [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140617/diagonal-underbrace), but there were no parenthesis and I was not able to circumvent this.

[image: test]

Comment: Hi, just a curiosity...for my opinion your question is good and I put +1. But do you have seen this image (I never I have seen this in a textbook)? :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano : thanks for your encouraging comment. I did the image myself, but admittedly I never saw this in a book – maybe in the future if we get nice answers to my question ;-)

Comment: I don't even really know how to do it properly with a horizontal brace.

Comment: Yes, I'm agree fully with you....In this moment for me it is very complicated done it in math-mode. I think with TiKZ or PSTricks it is very simple. I have understood your thought. :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano : a solution with TikZ (or PSTricks that I don't really know) would be fine. This is the approach used in the quesiton I linked.

Comment: No no I have not seen truly your link. You wait a bit of time :-) . Here there are many excellents users.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267171/nested-mathematical-functions

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes : thanks, but I don't see how that question relates to mine about the digonal brace.

Comment: @Watson I did not realize the diagonal brace was the essential part.  I will see what I can do.

Comment: @Watson I'm sure that your question was very good :-)))))

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Very easy with horizontal brace; somewhat less easy with rotated brace. I have no time right now to implement a general solution, so I'll go with a brute-force version for now.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}% loads amsmath and graphicx

\begin{document}

\[
\biggl(\Bigl(\bigl(a
{% extra group for correct spacing
 \overbrace{
     {}^q \bigr)^q \Bigr)^{\rotatebox{20}{$\scriptstyle\dots$}} \biggr)^{\!\!q\mathstrut}
 }^{\text{$n$ times}}
}
\]

\[
\biggl(
\Bigl(
\bigl(a^q\bigr)^{q}
\Bigr)\quad
\biggr)^{
         \!\! q
         \setbox0=\hbox to 0pt{\hss
            \rotatebox{15}{$
              \overbrace{\kern1.8em\scriptstyle\mathstrut\dots\kern1.2em}^{\rotatebox{-15}{\scriptsize$n$ times}}
            $}%
         }%
         \lower1.5ex\box0
        }
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer :-). In the horizontal case, it is possible to make the overbrace closer to the math formula? I tried to use \overbracket from mathtools but I am not able to get what I want. I tried to implement solutions from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13843/vertical-spacing-with-underbrace-command), but negative depth does not seem to work anyway...

Comment: Probably using your idea with "\lower3ex\box0" can make it work, but I am not sure how.

Comment: @Watson No, you need no `\lower` in the first case. I've put an extra `\mathstrut` to increase the distance; you can simply remove that.

Comment: Excellent works for every user! +1 for all.

Answer (score 11):

As given in my answer at [Nested Mathematical Functions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267171/nested-mathematical-functions/267172#267172)

The `.4pt` stacking gap added with each nesting will determine the growth rate of the parens.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine,graphicx,amsmath}
\stackMath
\ignoremathstyle
\newcommand\Comp[1]{\scaleleftright{(}{\addstackgap[.4pt]{#1}}{)}}
\newcommand\rdots{\ThisStyle{.\raisebox{.1ex}{$\scriptstyle.$}%
  \raisebox{.2ex}{$\scriptstyle.$}}}
\begin{document} 
\[ 
\stackinset{r}{1pt}{t}{-14.5pt}{\rotatebox{6}
  {$\overbrace{\rule{30pt}{0pt}}^{\textrm{\tiny$n$ times}}$}}{%
\Comp{\Comp{\Comp{a^q}^q}^{\rdots}}^q}
\] 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a version where the stackgap is increased to `.6pt`, to bring out the increasing size of parens:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but you are missing the diagonal brace above the parenthesis, so this does not really address my question.

Comment: @Watson Please see my revision.

Answer (score 8):

A solution with `pstricks-add`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\[
\biggl(\Bigl(\bigl(a^{\pnode[0,1ex]{E}{q}}\bigr)^{\! \rnode{F}{\scriptstyle q}}\Bigr)\enspace \biggr)^{\!\!\rnode{G}{\scriptstyle q}\pnode[0,1ex]{H}}%
\psset{singleline, braceWidth=1.2pt, braceWidthInner=2pt, braceWidthOuter=2pt, nodesepB=-2pt}
\psbrace[rot=14,ref=c, linewidth=0.3pt](H)(E){\scriptstyle n\:\mathrm{times}}%
\ncline[linestyle=dotted, dotsep=2.pt, nodesepA=4.5pt, nodesepB=3.2pt]{F}{G}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]